# how to create javascript array contain key and value?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

there is few text boxes im generating dynamically with a counter so its looks like this

```
form.append('Street: <input type="text" id="street'+counter+'" /> city: <input type="text" id="city'+counter+'" /><br/>'); 
counter++;
```

then im doing this to make a array

```
var array = [];
for(i=1; i<counter; i++){
array.push({'a':$('#street' + i).val(),'b':$('#city' + i).val()});          
}   
console.log(array);
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "dummy.php",
  data: array,
  success: function(response, textStatus, xhr) {
  },
  error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  }
});
```

but the problem is when im trying to send array to php script via ajax im getting 
Parameters
undefined undefined
undefined undefined

in post section of firebug

what im doing wrong here?

firebug console looks like with console.log(array) [image: firebug output]

Regards

**Seems like i found the solution 
i sent data like 
    data: {Addresses:array},
and it works**

Comment: How are you sending the request? Please post the code. Also make a `console.log(array)` after you created the array to inspect the values.

Comment: Where is the code which uploads the data?

Comment: This is firebug console looks like with console.log(array)  http://i53.tinypic.com/5mius3.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could send your form as-is like this (don't send as array):

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  data: form.serialize()
  ...
});
```

and turn it to an array in your server code.

Or, alternatively, you could name your inputs in a way they will automagically become two arrays on the server:

```
form.append('Street: <input type="text" name="street[]" /> city: <input type="text" name="city[]" /><br/>'); 
$.ajax({
  ...
  data: form.serialize()
  ...
});
```

And your PHP script would recieve `$_POST['street']` and `$_POST['city']` as arrays.
Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: i want to insert these data like street,city in one row so if i use form.serialize im getting two arrays which is hard to work with though,  if i have street,city in one array like im trying to do, i will able to construct query easily

Comment: Seems like i found the solution 

i sent data like 

data: {Addresses:array},

and it works